# IIS Express doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a visual studio 2015 solution with mvc web application and it doesn't have any build errors. When I running that project it is stop iis express and show "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in chrome. But when I create sample project and run, it works fine.(All projects are using same .NET framework) Please tell me possible issue in this.
I've changed localhost port to fix my issue (According to some other stackoverflow question thread). But it doesn't work. 
Please give me a solution.

> Update 1

Solution has 9 Projects. 8 Projects are class libraries and one project is web project. Web project set as startup project. port is 23693 and it is not used HTTPS.

[image]

Comment: That error message alone is useless. You have to also tell us about the project setup, like which ports it binds to and whether HTTPS is enabled.

Comment: I added extra information as you asked in "update 1" section.

Answer (score 0):

I install .NET core package and could resolve this issue.